# Populating a Numpy Array using FOR loop with DELETE and INSERT

Tags: python, numpy, insert

So far all the "mistakes" I've been making have been small things I'm missing, hopefully this is the case here.  I've decided to use NUMPY array mainly for the array resizing capability.  I've noticed that it takes awhile to import, but it's essentially doing what I need so beggars can't be choosers.  Anyway, while trying to "delete" items from the array and replacing them via "insert" with new data, I still have an array that contains all zeroes.  So, I'm at a loss.  I know the values for [archstartred], [archstartgrn], and [archstartblu] are correct because I print them when they're generated.  Why are the values not populating into the array?  Here's my code:

```
#Frame Creation

from numpy import *
frames=array([0 for i in range (0,workingframes*archnodes*3)])
frames.resize(archnodes*3, workingframes)


#Frame Population

for f in range (0, workingframes):

    if f<=(workingframes/2):

        for x in range (0, archnodes):
            delete(frames,[x+f])
            insert(frames,[x+f],(archstartred[x]))
            print archstartred[x]
            delete(frames,[x+f+workingframes])
            insert(frames,[x+f+workingframes],(archstartgrn[x]))
            print archstartgrn[x]
            delete(frames,[x+f+workingframes*2])
            insert(frames,[x+f+workingframes*2],(archstartblu[x]))
            print archstartblu[x]

        print frames
        raw_input('Press control c')  #stop/troubleshoot program


        for y in range (0, nodesperframe):
            archstartred.pop()
            archstartgrn.pop()
            archstartblu.pop()
            archstartred.insert(0, backred)
            archstartgrn.insert(0, backgrn)
            archstartblu.insert(0, backblu)

        archstartred = [int(value) for value in archstartred]
        archstartgrn = [int(value) for value in archstartgrn]
        archstartblu = [int(value) for value in archstartblu]

    else:
        for y in range (0, nodesperframe):
            archstartred.pop(0)
            archstartgrn.pop(0)
            archstartblu.pop(0)
            archstartred.append(backred)
            archstartgrn.append(backgrn)
            archstartblu.append(backblu)

        archstartred = [int(value) for value in archstartred]
        archstartgrn = [int(value) for value in archstartgrn]
        archstartblu = [int(value) for value in archstartblu]

        for x in range (0, archnodes):
            delete(frames,[x+f])
            insert(frames,[x+f],(archstartred[x]))
            delete(frames,[x+f+workingframes])
            insert(frames,[x+f+workingframes],(archstartgrn[x]))
            delete(frames,[x+f+workingframes*2])
            insert(frames,[x+f+workingframes*2],(archstartblu[x]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numpy functions `insert` and `delete` return a copy rather than occurring in-place. Assign the result back to `frames` rather than discarding it.

Comment: I thought that's what I was doing.  So, how would I do that?

Comment: Hmmmm... that changes the original attributes of the array which I need to keep for data formatting issues.

Comment: If you are just trying to assign a row, use the syntax `frames[row_num] = new_row`.

Comment: I just realized that the loop isn't generating data correctly

Comment: Regardless of my loop, according to the Numpy Example List (http://www.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List/), this is the right way to remove/add to the array.  If the array was 1 by [archnodes*3*workingframes], would it not work better?

Comment: While that would probably work, if you want to replace a row or column of a 2-dimensional array, the indexed assignment with `[]` is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Since I'm not wanting to replace the whole row or column, just a specific value, would it be better to use () instead of []?

Comment: That doesn't make sense: `()` are for function calls or grouping, not item access/assignment. If you want to only change one value, rather than a whole row or column, use `frames[row_num, col_num] = new_val`.

Comment: OK, I'll try that and keep you posted.  I get away from this thing for right now though.